# UITableViewController on UISplitView. Why does drill down stay on 1st table? (using monotouch)

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uisplitview

I'm using the UISplitView in my app with the left side (popover in portrait) utilizing a UITableViewController. I want to reuse the master table controller so when I want to drill down I create a new instance of the object and push that. However, when I set the data source, all the data goes into the 1st instance table (hope that makes sense). So if I hit the back button, the new data I thought was supposed to be on the pushed table is in the 1st table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I sort of figured it out. I have an asynchronous operation occuring and it seems to have something to do with threading. When i call the method synchronously, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When updating things in a callback you should use InvokeOnMainThread();

Otherwise you'll end up in a bad state :)

w://